# Getting return type of generic method call in AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I've got generic method `Foo.foo()`:

```
class Foo {
    static native T <T> foo();
}

Bar bar = Foo.foo();
```

What I need is to replace calls to this method using AspectJ. The problem is that to return a value of type T from the aspect, I need to know what T is. How can I do this with AspectJ?

Here is one solution I've tried:

```
Object around() : call(* Foo.foo(..)) {
    Class target = ((MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature()).getReturnType();
    System.out.println("class = " + class);
}
```

It returns `Object` as the class of return type. How can I determine that call to `foo()` should actually return instance of `Bar`?

Answer (score 7):

I have not checked it, but I believe this should work.

```
Method method = ((MethodSignature) thisJoinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
Type type = method.getGenericReturnType();
System.out.println("type = " + type);
```

Please take a look at the javadoc at here: [Method#getGenericReturnType()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType%28%29)

Comment: It just returns type variable T, without any bounds or actual type.

Comment: Field#getGenericType() returns type of the field at runtime and it works for me, i m not sure about method though :-S. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType%28%29

Comment: if(type.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ParameterizedTypeImpl")) 
{
    String actualType =Arrays.stream(((ParameterizedTypeImpl) type).getActualTypeArguments()).findFirst().get().getTypeName();
    System.out.println("actualType = " + actualType.toString());
}

Answer (score 0):

At runtime you won't be able to discern that. The substitution of Bar for T is erased at compile-time, and so would be unavailable to your advice.

If MethodSignature offered something like getGenericReturnType(), the best it'd be able to tell you is that the return type of Foo.foo() is T. It'd be interrogating the generics info baked into the class file for Foo, rather than being able to figure out from a runtime call what the intended type was.

Another question for you: how does Foo.foo() know to return Bar?

Comment: Well, I know about type erasure. But AspectJ takes source files, not compiled classes, so it might be possible for ajc to compute and save return type somewhere while parsing the source.

Comment: For instance, javac in its internal representation embeds explicit type cast to Bar after call to Foo.

Comment: And Foo.foo() doesn't "know" anything - the only implementation of it should be in AspectJ. It's not an actual native method.